# How do I use es6 syntax with split?

Tags: javascript

```
         const {city, country} = input.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

These are both undefined.

Input is `los gatos, california`

Comment: `const {city, country}` -> `const [city, country]`

Comment: `[v1, v2]` instead since split returns an array not an object

Comment: How do I access it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: *How do I access it?* You get `city` and `country` as separate variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.split` results in an array output but you're destructuring it as if it were an object.

Do

```js
const [city, country] = 'los gatos, california'.split(/\s*,\s*/);
console.log(city);
console.log(country);
```

You destructure by using array destructuring ([..]) instead of object ({..})